# Need Meyers Effective C++ Widget rvalue example explanation

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I have a little C++ question.

On the first pages of Effective Modern C++, there is an example:

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(Widget&& rhs);
};
```

Also, there is a comment: 'rhs is an lvalue, though it has an rvalue reference type'.

I just understood nothing, to be honest. What does it mean 'rhs is an lvalue, but it's type is rvalue reference'?

Comment: Well, thanks for the explanation, guys, I finally got it! Everybody honored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep in mind that there are two distinct things here:

- One is related to *the type of variables*: there are two types of references: lvalue references (`&`) and rvalue references (`&&`).

  This determines what the function preferentially accepts and is always "obvious" because you can just read it from the type signature (or use `decltype`).
- The other is a *property of expressions* (or values): an expression can be an lvalue or an rvalue ([actually, it's more complicated than that...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602)).

  This property is not manifest in the code directly (but there is a rule of thumb, see below), but you can see its effects in the overload resolution.  In particular,

  - lvalue arguments prefer to bind to lvalue-reference parameters, whereas
  - rvalue arguments prefer to bind to rvalue-reference parameters.

These properties are closely related (and in some sense "dual" to each other), but they don't necessarily agree with each other.  In particular, it's important to realize that *variables* and *expressions* are actually different things, so formally speaking they aren't even comparable, "apples to oranges".

---

There is this rule in C++ that, even though you have declared `rhs` to be an rvalue reference (meaning that it will preferentially match *arguments* that are rvalues), within the block of move constructor, the variable `rhs` itself will still *behave as an lvalue*, and thus preferentially match functions that accept lvalue references.

```
void test(Widget&&) { std::cout << "test(Widget&&): called\n"; }
void test(Widget&)  { std::cout << "test(Widget&): called\n"; }

Widget::Widget(Widget&& rhs) {
    // here, `rhs` is an lvalue, not an rvalue even though
    // its type is declared to be an rvalue reference

    // for example, this will match `test(Widget&)`
    // rather than the `test(Widget&&)` overload, which may be
    // a bit counter-intuitive
    test(rhs);

    // if you really want to match `test(Widget&&)`
    // you must use `std::move` to "wrap" the variable
    // so that it can be treated as an rvalue
    test(std::move(rhs));
}
```

The rationale for this was to prevent unintended moves within the move constructor.

*The general rule of thumb is:* if the expression has a *name* (i.e. consists of a single, named variable) then it's an lvalue.  If the expression is anonymous, then it's an rvalue.  (As dyp noted, this is not technically correct -- see his comment for a more formal description.)

Comment: And you use `std::move()` to get rid of its name (turn it into an rvalue).

Comment: *"even though you have declared `rhs` to be an rvalue reference [...], the variable `rhs` itself will still behave as an lvalue"* I think in Standardese, one would say *even though you have declared a variable/parameter with the name `rhs` and the type 'rvalue reference to `Widget`', an expression referring to that variable is an lvalue-expression.*

Comment: Similarly: *"if the expression has a name"* expressions do not have names. Expressions can contain names / "names" (identifiers as expressions, i.e. id-expressions) can be expressions. An identifier-expression is an lvalue, unless it refers to an enumerator. (But I'm nitpicking, +1)

Comment: I'm sort of quoting what someone else has said, but yes it's technically incorrect to equate expressions and variables.  I didn't want to bog down the answer with too much Standardese though :)

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple explanation :P

```
Widget(Widget&& rhs);
```

is a move constructor. It will accept a rvalue as a parameter. Inside the definition of the move constructor, you can refer to the other Widget using the name rhs, therefore it is an lvalue.